# Having problems with scheduling of a batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a java class, which I needed to schedule. So I created a batch file which calls the java class. The bat file is fairly simple

```
java -cp ".:classname.jar;********" MyJavaClass
```

But when I schedule this as Windows Task Scheduler, the task scheduler show the task run at the trigger but the I can see that Java Class didn't actually perform what it was supposed to do.

I know there is no problem in bat file because when I run it manually it works totally fine.

I am setting to Store Password and the user selected for the batch job is added to Logon as Batch Job.

What could be the problem.

Comment: Did you check/set **current directory** for batch? If you run it manually then it'll be its own directory but Task Scheduler will use `%Windir%\System32`. Also...why do you need batch for this and you do not directly invoke your program?

Comment: Your classpath is defined with the relative directory `.`.  If the working dir of the task is not what you think when the Task Scheduler starts it, some classes are probably not found.

Comment: Have you specify the directory in Scheduler(Action)->Start in(Optional).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check/Set current directory for batch file is the solution

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have a problem with the windows scheduler.
It could be helpful if you give us information about your os and maybe the command(s) you used to set up the scheduler / the command(s) the scheduler is executing.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If you do not have enough rep to comment then just wait, few nice answers and you'll have that privilege enabled.